# AsynTask cancel long running operation like HttpGet

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've seen several [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724640/asynctask-is-not-cancelling-the-long-running-operation-in-android) about canceling an AsynTask, but I don't think any of them resolves the issues. Imagine this scenario:

```
public class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object> {

@Override
protected void onCancelled(Object result) {
    running = false;
    Log.i("Test", "onCancelled");
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Log.i("Test", "cancelling");
            cancel(true);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Log.i("Test", "Past sleep");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.i("Test", "InterruptedException", e);
        }

    return null;
}

}
```

Imagine I'd like to cancel this long 20 second request in the middle of a download, for example if the server is responding slow to a json request. So the Thread.sleep(5000) could be a HttpGet request that I'd like to cancel. However the cancel method is marked as final so I can't override it and call get.abort(). The onCancel hook happens after the doInBackground and back on the UI thread. Checking for isCancel won't do me any good once the HttpGet request has started.

The way I solve this is to make an abort() method on my AsynTask and just call that.

```
public void abort() {
   get.abort();
   cancel(true);
}
```

but this seems to go against the Android grain a bit. Is there a better way to cancel the request?

Comment: Wouldn't you still need to read the bytes off the `InputStream` for your connection? You just need to check is the task `isCancelled` as you call `read` on the stream, exactly as it is shown in the answer for the question you linked to. It will kill the download as soon as you cancel the task. If you are referring to waiting for a timeout, you can use the `setReadTimeout` on the `HttpUrlConnection`.

Comment: No. I'm talking about wanting to use HttpGet.abort(). There is no way to call this when using AsynTask when using httpClient.execute(HttpGet). if I check isCancelled() after the "execute" well the execute has already finished. I want to abort the download not just stop the logic after it.

Comment: @ebarrenchea Has the right answer, but did not mention you should be checking `isCancelled()` in `doInBackground()`, where the stream would ideally be read. See the section [cancelling an `AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: This does not cancel the Http request. It only stops further executing.

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs for `HttpGet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest.html#abort%28%29), there is no mention of thread safety, so calling `abort()` the way you described will probably lead to undesired results (at best). What you could do is pass an `HttpGet` object in the constructor for your `AsyncTask`, or via a setter (as long you do this before you call `AsyncTask.execute()`).

You would have to check periodically inside of `doInBackground()` if the task has been cancelled:

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // start GET request
        try {
            Log.i("Test", "cancelling");
            cancel(true);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Log.i("Test", "Past sleep");

            if ( this.isCancelled() ) {
               // abort GET request and/or stop doing other work
               return null;
            }
            else {
                // do what ever work you need to
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.i("Test", "InterruptedException", e);
        }

    return null;
}
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29).

You can always call `AsyncTask.cancel(true)` whenever you feel the task should be stopped ([`AsyncTask.cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29))

Comment: thanks for the comment. Checking isCancelled would only stop future code execution. It will not cancel the current request. assume the Get takes 20 seconds. With this solution there isn't a way to cancel that 20 second period. Passing an HttpGet via a setter or constructor would still lead to same thread issues you've suggested. However, I'm really not worried about that.

Comment: @user123321 You could keep a timer somewhere else, when it is finished, check if the operation is compplete, if not, cancel it. The mechanism to cancel an `AsyncTask` is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is applicable or not, but you could create another thread using an executor service that executes the download-task and keep checking for `isCancelled()` inside `doInBackground()` or until the future object returns, whichever happens first:

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Void... params)
{
    Callable<Void> downlaodTask = new Callable<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception
        {
            // download task here

            return null;
        }
    };

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<Void> future = executor.submit(downlaodTask);

    while(true) // check every second
    {
        try
        {
            future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // wait until the download task finishes with 1 second as a timeout
            break;
        }
        catch(TimeoutException e)
        {
            if(isCancelled())
            {
                executor.shutdownNow(); // or abort() or both
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```